# How to get require() to accept decimal value of ether in payable functions in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, payable, require

On using,

1. `require(msg.value == registerFeeMap[msg.sender] /_currentRate)` 
   (fractional ETH value calculated)
2. `require(msg.value == registerFeeMap[msg.sender]*10**18/ _currentRate)`
   (ETH converted to Wei)
3. `require((msg.value*10**18) == registerFeeMap[msg.sender]*10**18/ _currentRate)`

in, 
`function feePayment(string _sign, uint _currentRate) external payable`
on using all 3 I get, VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

1. `_currentRate` is parameter for function `feePayment(string _sign, uint _currentRate) external payable` here, _sign is the MetaMask signed message string and _currentRate is INR vs ETH value from CryptoCompare API.
2. `registerFeeMap` is initialised in `function newHome(string _add, string _type, uint _startEpoch, uint _endEpoch, uint _months, uint _rent, uint _security) external` with values depending on `_rent` variable.

**Example value stored in registerFeeMap >= 100**
**Example value of _currentRate from API = 8380**

**How should I convert Eth to Wei for require(), if fractional value of Ether is to be used for payments ?**

**My Contract Code is as follows**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Owned {

address owner;

function Owned() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}
}


contract Rent is Owned {    
struct Person {

    address eth;
    string legalName;
    string email;
    uint aadhaar;

    string signTerms; //sign on the Terms and Conditions

    uint[] myOwned;
    uint[] myRented;
}

struct Parties {

    address landlord;
    address tenant;

    string signLandlord;
    string signTenant;

    bool completed;
}


struct House {

    string addressHouse;
    string type_of_property;

    uint startEpoch;
    uint endEpoch; 

    uint monthDuration; // difference in Months of these Dates

    uint rentAmount;
    uint securityFee;
    uint registerFee;

    bool completed;
}

struct OtherDetails {

    string latitude;
    string longitude;

    string ipfs_url; // for Future Versions of, when we support IPFS URLs

    uint squareFootage;
    uint numberBedrooms;
    string others;

    bool completed;
}

struct Checks {

    bool isValid;

    bool tenantApprove;
    bool govApprove;

    bool tenantCheck;

    bool paidRegisterFee;
    bool paidSecurityFee;
}

Parties[] public allParties; 
House[] public allHouses;
OtherDetails[] public allOtherDetails;
Checks[] private allChecks;

mapping(address => Person) public addressToPerson;
mapping(address => bool) private checkUser;
mapping(uint => bool) private checkAadhaar;

mapping(address => uint) private registerFeeMap;
mapping(address => uint) private securityFeeMap;


function Rent() public {

    checkUser[owner] = true;
    var govt = Person(owner, 'Owner', 'Owner', 0, 'No Sign', new uint[](0), new uint[](0));

    addressToPerson[owner] = govt;
}


event registerParty(string message);

function registerParties(address _tenant) external  {

    require(msg.sender != _tenant);

    if(checkUser[msg.sender] == true)
    {
        if(checkUser[_tenant] == true)
        {
            var newParty = Parties(msg.sender, _tenant,'N/A', 'N/A', true);
            var index = allParties.push(newParty) - 1;

            var newHouse = House('No Address Added', 'No Property Type', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false);
            allHouses.push(newHouse);

            var newDetails = OtherDetails('28.7041', '77.1025', 'Currently IPFS Not Supported', 0, 0, 'N/A', false);
            allOtherDetails.push(newDetails);

            var newChecks = Checks(false, false, false, false, false, false);
            allChecks.push(newChecks);

            var user = addressToPerson[msg.sender];
            user.myOwned.push(index);

            var tenant = addressToPerson[_tenant];
            tenant.myRented.push(index);

            registerParty('Tenant was Successfully added to Contract, Proceed to Step 2');
        }

        else
        {
            registerParty('Tenant is not registered on Charter, registration of both parties is required');
        }
    }

    else
    {
        registerParty('Kindly register on Charter, before drafting a Contract');
    }
}


event registerHome(string message, uint FeePayable);

function newHome(string _add, string _type, uint _startEpoch, uint _endEpoch, uint _months, uint _rent, uint _security) external {

    if(checkUser[msg.sender] == true)
    {
        var user = addressToPerson[msg.sender];

        uint num = user.myOwned.length - 1;

        if(num < 0)
        {
            registerHome('Kindly fill Tenant Info in Step 1 before proceeding to Step 2', 0);
        }

        else
        {
            uint index = user.myOwned[num];
            var houseOwner = allParties[index];

            if(houseOwner.landlord != msg.sender)
            {
                registerHome('Kindly register on Charter, before drafting a Contract', 0);
            }

            else
            {
                var home = allHouses[index];

                if(home.completed == false)
                {
                    home.addressHouse = _add;
                    home.type_of_property = _type;

                    home.startEpoch = _startEpoch;
                    home.endEpoch = _endEpoch;

                    home.monthDuration = _months;

                    home.rentAmount = _rent;
                    home.securityFee = _security;

                    var _tenant = allParties[index].tenant; 

                    if((home.monthDuration < 12)&&(home.monthDuration > 0))
                    {
                        home.registerFee = 100;
                        home.completed = true;

                        registerHome("Property's Information successfully entered, Proceed to Step-3", home.registerFee);
                    }

                    else if(home.monthDuration <= 60)
                    {
                        if(_security > 0)
                        home.registerFee = 100 + ((2 * 12 * _rent) / 100) + 1100;

                        else
                        home.registerFee = ((2 * 12 * _rent) / 100) + 1100;

                        home.completed = true;

                        registerHome("Property's Information successfully entered, Proceed to Step-3", home.registerFee);
                    }

                    else if(home.monthDuration <= 120)
                    {
                        if(_security > 0)
                        home.registerFee = 100 + ((3 * 12 * _rent) / 100) + 1100;

                        else
                        home.registerFee = ((3 * 12 * _rent) / 100) + 1100;     

                        home.completed = true;

                        registerHome("Property's Information successfully entered, Proceed to Step-3", home.registerFee);       
                    }

                    else if(home.monthDuration <= 240)
                    {
                        if(_security > 0)
                        home.registerFee = 100 + ((6 * 12 * _rent) / 100) + 1100;

                        else
                        home.registerFee = ((6 * 12 * _rent) / 100) + 1100;

                        home.completed = true;
                        registerHome("Property's Information successfully entered, Proceed to Step-3", home.registerFee);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        home.completed = false;
                        registerHome('Kindly Enter Duration of Contract Correctly.. (Min - 1 month, Max - 240 Months' , 0);
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    registerHome('Home Registration is already Completed ', 0);
                }

                registerFeeMap[msg.sender] = home.registerFee;
                securityFeeMap[_tenant] = home.securityFee;
            }

        }
    }

    else
    {
        registerHome('Kindly register on Charter, before drafting a Contract', 0);
    }
}



event feePay(string message);

function feePayment(string _sign, uint _currentRate) external payable {

    require(msg.value == (registerFeeMap[msg.sender] * 10**18 / _currentRate));

    if(checkUser[msg.sender] == true)
    {
        var user = addressToPerson[msg.sender];

        uint num = user.myOwned.length - 1;

        if(num < 0)
        {
            feePay('Complete all the Steps, before paying Registration Fee Payment');
        }

        else
        {

            uint index = user.myOwned[num];
            var party = allParties[index];
            var house = allHouses[index];
            var details = allOtherDetails[index];
            var checks = allChecks[index];

            if((details.completed == true)&&(house.completed == true)&&(party.completed == true))
            {
                user = addressToPerson[msg.sender];
                checks.paidRegisterFee = true;
                party.signLandlord = _sign;

                feePay('Government Registration Fee Payment Successful, Tenant Verification pending..');
            }

            else 
            {
                feePay('Complete all the Steps given above before Fee Payment');
            }
        }
    }

    else
    {
        feePay('Kindly register on Charter, before drafting a Contract');
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to know without seeing the values. One problem I see right off the bat is that you use `10^18` rather than `10**18`. Try that.

Comment: Here is a simple conclusion from your description: `msg.value != registerFeeMap[msg.sender] * 10^18 / _currentRate`. Other than that, it is not clear what you are asking, not what you are trying to achieve. If you're hoping to get help here, then you should consider explaining yourself properly (including all the code necessary to reproduce whatever problem it is that you're struggling with).

Comment: I am calculating payments in INR (this value is stored in registerFeeMap mapping, eg 100), the function parameter _currentRate holds value of INR vs Eth conversion rate (eg 8,380 INR for 1 ether), the division of  `registerFeeMap[msg.sender]  / _currentRate` can yield a decimal value (100 / 8380), how to handle payments when value of ETH calculated is in fractions.

Comment: `require(msg.value == registerFeeMap[msg.sender] * 10**18 / _currentRate)` gives the same error. VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Comment: Please elaborate on how you have initialized `registerFeeMap[msg.sender]` and `_currentRate`, and what value you are passing when you call the function.

Comment: `mapping(address => uint) private registerFeeMap` is initialized with value - `registerFeeMap[msg.sender] = home.registerFee` calculated as `home.registerFee = 100 + ((3 * 12 * _rent) / 100) + 1100` here `uint  _rent` is a function parameter. And, `_currentRate` is parameter for  `function feePayment(string _sign, uint _currentRate) external payable`,  _sign is the MetaMask signed message string and _currentRate is INR vs Eth value from CryptoCompare API (example value - 8380).

Comment: Right... that was as clear as a foggy day in Beijing. Please post it as part of your question, and try to do so in an organized fashionable manner.

Comment: @anudishjain What are values you are using. Because since you are using, `100* 10**18/8380 = 11933174224343676` returns  a non decimal value.

Comment: The 10**18 operation used was to convert the Ether to Wei, if I calculate this value in just Ether it would be 100/8380 = 0.01193317422, which is in decimals

Comment: This is ridiculous! Your notion of bits and pieces of your code alongside a short description is useless. Instead of explaining your code, just post it! And please make sure that you include the following: 1. The solidity function. 2. How you call it (i.e., with what parameters). 3. How you initialize each state-variable used by the function (i.e., with what values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Example value stored in registerFeeMap - 100
> >     Example value of _currentRate from API - 8380

In uint math

```
100/8380 = 0
```

identically (i.e. always).

So if your msg.value is different from zero, your first require argument is not true and reverts.

The second one is wrong, ‘^’ operator for elevation is a mistake.

The third one should be:

```
 (A * 10**18 / B) / 10**18
```

or you can multiply msg.value * 10**18 before to compare to it.

This as general discussion about division in Solidity.

But are you sure to be tuned on msg.value properties?

Msg.value is expressed in wei.

Are you worried about 0.01193317422 wei?

I don’t think so. Read your data and print them to console. You will be more confident after that.

(1 wei = 1 ether / 10**18, I.e. 0.000000000000000001 ether)

Comment: tried `require((msg.value*10**18) == registerFeeMap[msg.sender]*10**18/ _currentRate)` got same error, how to make require take fractional value of Ether as 100 / 8380 = 0.01193317422

Comment: Msg.value is expressed in wei. Are you worried about 0.01193317422 wei? I don’t think so. Read your data and print them to console. You will be more confident after that. (1 wei = 1 ether / 10**18, I.e. 0.000000000000000001 ether)